# How to fix "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc()" on php and sql?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I tried to read all my database rows with PHP. When trying to print them out, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php(24): mysqli_fetch_assoc(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php on line 24

I don't know how to fix it. I searched answers on the internet, but didn't find enything. Here's my code:

```
<?php
require "configure.php";

$db_handle = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

$database = "test2";

$db_found = mysqli_select_db($db_handle, $database);

if($db_found){
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_test_2";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $SQL);

    while($db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $db_field["ID"]."<br>";
        echo $db_field["COUNTRY"]."<br>";
        echo $db_field["NAME"]."<br>";
        echo $db_field["Birthday"]."<br>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "Database not found";
}
mysqli_close($db_handle);
?>
```

Configure.php:

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
?>
```

I use xampp for viewing the code.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Comment: _Small Point Not your problem i dont think_ You can add the database name to the 4th param of `mysqli_connect()` so you dont need the `mysqli_select_db()` unless you are switching databases within a piece of code

Comment: Basically the query has failed, but that query is so simple and basic that probably means you spelt the table name incorrectly

Comment: Oh, thanks. I don't noticed that...